# Would a "silent" sound cancel out other sounds?

Tags: acoustics

For example: you want to have silence for a few minutes but you only had earbuds. Could you, lets say, go on YouTube and listen to a video with VERY quiet sound and it would destructively interfere with the sound from outside, therefore creating silence? I'm not saying white noise, I mean completely inaudible to the human ear sound, such as ultrasonic sound.

Answer (score 4):

Sound is a (longitudinal) vibration of air molecules. "Silent sound" can only mean no vibration at all. Just as a value does not change if we add 0 to it, equally a sound does not change if we add no sound to it.

However, it is possible to cancel sound by playing a vibration that is exactly opposite to the one you want to cancel. This is done in [Noise Cancelling Headphones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-cancelling_headphones). In those phones, a little microphone picks up the sound in the environment outside the phone, and adds that to the music played inside. The result is that the extraneous noise is greatly reduced - in the ideal case it would disappear altogether. Such headphones are readily available. I have a pair which I use when flying. They work great, especially with a constant drone like the one you hear in a plane. They do not work as well with sudden noises.

Of course, there is one other way to cancel sound: use perfectly good earmuffs, that let no sound through at all. That method is possibly the closest to your idea of "silent sound": all you are hearing is indeed a silent sound, i.e. no sound at all. However, it does not do it by cancelling the noise, the earmuffs simply stop it from reaching your ears.